# UPSERT in Oracle

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, streaming, oracle19c

We have Oracle 19c and we want to stream data from Kafka to Oracle 19c through SPARK streaming. We want to use UPSERT operation to update / insert data in target oracle table. I know MERGE is available as alternate to UPSERT. But spark does not support MERGE. Is there any solution for spark to oracle UPSERT or any alternate for same?